# If a range contains certain value multiple times, paste the cell next to it in specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to check through a range for a cell value, and then paste the cell to the left in a different location. HOWEVER, I can not seem to figure out what to do if the range contains a value multiple times.

What I would like to do is if it contains a value twice (probably the maximum I will need to deal with) it will copy and paste each cell to the left in 2 different locations.

This is what I have right now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True

Set OtherRng = Range("A18:S42")
Set NewRng = Range("C18:C60")  

If Not Intersect(Target, OtherRng) Is Nothing Then

      For Each cell In NewRng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "41/N" Then
            Map.Cells(35, 18).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
        If cell.Value = "41/M" Then
            Map.Cells(35, 16).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
      Next

End sub
```

How can I make it so that if there are two values in `NewRng`that both contain "41/N" that it puts the `cell.offset(0,-1)` for the first value into `Map.cells(35,18)` (like it does now) and the `cell.offset(0,-1)` for the second value into `Map.cells(36,18)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim i as integer
i = 0

  For Each cell In NewRng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "41/N" Then
        Map.Cells(35+i, 18).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
```

There are better ways but for simplicity the above should do what you requested

Comment: @user3757447 Glad it works for you!  Keep in mind that the code does not check on column 18 hence there will be no warning if existing values being replaced

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of the VBA syntax, but you can keep a flag (or a counter) that you set (or increment) each time you see the given value. Then you select the cell to place the value in based off of the flag (or counter).

PseudoCode:

```
Seen_N = False
Seen_M = False
For Each cell in NewRng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "41/N" Then
        If Seen_N Then
            Map.Cells(36,18).Value = cell.Offset(0,-1)
        Else
            Map.Cells(35,18).Value = cell.Offset(0,-1)
            Seen_N = True
        End If
    End If
    If cell.Value = "41/M" Then
        If Seen_M Then
            Map.Cells(36,16).Value = cell.Offset(0,-1)
        Else
            Map.Cells(35,16).Value = cell.Offset(0,-1)
            Seen_M = True
        End If
    End If
  Next
```

This should be fine if this is just a one-off, but if you did want to consider the case where you have lots of those entries, use a counter and calculate the row from the counter (I.e. row = 35+ num_Seen_N.